# Best practice for setting up facebook comments for clients website, My facebook account vs theirs

Tags: comments, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I'm setting up a website (wordpress) for a client.
For comments to posts on their site, they've indicated they want to use facebook Social comments app.

Do I create the app using my facebook ID , or do I ask them to make me an admin for their page? 
Can I transfer an app some day  to them?

(I did a little searching on here, i'm sure the question has been asked,  perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology, as i'm not finding the answer i need)

Thank you for reading!

Comment: You can create the app, then add multiple developers to it in the same way a page can have multiple admins.

Comment: @cpilko Thank you for taking the time to answer! In practice are both methods equal in terms of "whats right" (me starting then adding them, or them adding the app and adding me as an admin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer depends on whether or not who will be moderating the comments and really "managing" the app. If your client would like to see/view/moderate comments, add them as a developer or a comment moderator. If you will be responsible, then obviously use your account.

Comment: Thank you! In the past, i've used Disqus etc.. Client wanted a facebook based comment plugin, hence my question. It seems, that building it with my own facebook profile is ok!